# how to access and assign new value in array/object in lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I am looking for simple easy way to assign new value through lodash. See the blow example. I only want to reassign value of first element of object of first element of arr array.

```
const arr = [
 {
   a: 'apple',
   b: 'banana',
   c: 'cat'
 },
 {
   a: 'apple-1',
   b: 'banana-2',
   c: 'cat-3'
 }
];

const newArr = arr;
const ele = ._first(newArr);// picked first element
ele['a'] = 'dog';
```

this is what I expect to see

```
console.log(newArr);
// [
 {
   a: 'dog', //<--- updated
   b: 'banana',
   c: 'cat'
 },
 {
   a: 'apple-1',
   b: 'banana-2',
   c: 'cat-3'
 }
];
```

thank you ahead!

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such thing as `the first element of object`.

Comment: whats going wrong. is it the typo you have `_.first` instead of `._first`

Comment: There is no need to have `newArr` as it refers to the same entity as `arr`. So you want `arr[0].a = "dog";`, but I don't know why you want lodash here =))

Comment: Thank you for caching my type @cmgchess! Yes, I was able to get expected code with my solution above but thought there should be way to make that code simpler with lodash..I guess no.. Do you have any other solution even without lodash. @
Kosh

Comment: @Cindy _.first is like taking the first element out of an array using [0]. see the answer below

Comment: @Kosh I wanted to use lodash because I thought I could find simple way. - like my question, if I can access and re-assign value one time with lodash. If lodash can't help my code simpler. Then I would remove! Thank you!

Comment: lodash can help in some cases but maybe not in your case above. for example if you want to extract first 3 from array you can use `_.first(arr,3)`

Comment: @cmgchess yes, that is what I wanted to do. I was looking for way to access first key-value of first object of first element of arr and reassign new value. I am sorry maybe my example makes more confusion...

Comment: can I assign new value with _.first(arr,3)?

Comment: my question is more like can we make const ele = ._first(newArr); ele['a'] = 'dog'; these two lines code can be simpler with lodash @cmgchess

Comment: no it is not simpler with lodash in your case. you have to download lodash so extra dependancy , import it before using it. while it can be easily done using native js. see the answer below

Comment: I mean, I am already using lodash in other side of code so it isn't that big issue. But since there is no simple method in lodash. I will just stick to js only! no more lodash. Thank you for your help @cmgchess

Comment: Lodash can do some complex stuff for sure. Your given example is too simple for lodash that you won't need it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you cannot just use simple JS without lodash?

```js
const arr = [
 {
   a: 'apple',
   b: 'banana',
   c: 'cat'
 },
 {
   a: 'apple-1',
   b: 'banana-2',
   c: 'cat-3'
 }
];

const newArr = arr;
newArr[0].a = 'dog'

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: yes, I can do so! Only reason why I added lodash because I thought I could find easier way with ladash. just like my question - is there any way I can access and reassign value in [{key: this value}, {key: value}] with lodash? But I guess, there is no way to do so. Again, my example is causing.. some confusion.. sorry about it.